# Black screen on login and then flickering of GUI elements on Nvidia 9500GS

Tags: 11.04, installation, nvidia, graphics

Last week i tried to install Ubuntu 11.04 and i have a problem i cannot solve.

Mit Grafics Card is an Nvidia 9500GS which worked well with Ubuntu, Compiz and stuff before.

The Problem:

- i installed Ubuntu 11.04 from the life cd besides an Windows 7 Home Premium
- When i boot up ubuntu everything seems to be right
- The logon screen appears
- When i log in the screen is black in an interval of less then a second i can see the gui elements (panels, desktop icons etc.. flickering).
- The only way i can shutdown the system now is doing it the hardware-way

What i tryied so far (1. Attemp):

- i logged into the Safe-Mode which works well
- i tryied to install the nvidia properitary drivers through the gui this does not work saying "Can't find a valid source for the driver"
- i activated the nvidia driver through the console with jockey which worked. In the gui there was the green dot then
- rebooting, trying to log in again **Same Problem**

What i tryied so far (2. Attemp):

- so i rembered that in some versions of ubuntu in the past i had to install fresh nvidia drivers downloaded from their website.
- i downloaded the drivers from nvidia
- tryied to start them (unfortunately the installation process requires to switch off X Server) which i tried by the way i knew (sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop). Which tells me "Use sudo service gdm stop" or something similar. I tried that without success.
- Then i tried to switch to a console without gui by hitting "strg+alt+f1" but this results in eternal black. I can then switch back to the gui through "strg+alt+f7".

So the problem with my second attemp is, that i can't get a console without a gui and i can't install nvidia drivers with the gui ant i can't shutdown the gui while being in the gui (spooky)...

So do you have any ideas, what i did wrong or what i could try to get this fixed again? Maybe its not a Graphics Problem at all and you know better?

Comment: Try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual Also see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: Mhm... thanks four the links. But in know everything in there. This does not solve my problem or even adresses it. My Problem is before installing Nvidia software.

Comment: I see. what happens when you do sudo service gdm stop?

Answer (score 2):

try to install latest driver

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-glx-185
```

If you getting any problem after install then log with recovery mode[2nd option of grub menu] go to root shell.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove nvidia-glx-185
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i got this to work yesterday afternoon before i read this answer here so i didn't try this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the information. i couldn't get the service to stop and also no console windows without gui, but i solved the main problem. For some reason i had to make all updates in the safe mode. After that, i was able to install the NVidia driver through the jockey-gui successfully.

Now i habe a nice 11.04 installation with unitiy and everything working nice.